# How to logout from facebook using expo-facebook

Tags: react-native, facebook, facebook-graph-api, expo

I have been trying to logout/end the session of the current logged in user so that any other user can login. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#logoutasync expo-facebook provides logOutAsync() method but its not working. How can I logout programmatically? is there any graphQl API, unable to find any.

Answer (score 0):

You should import expo facebook

`import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';`

and call logOutAsync

`Facebook.logOutAsync();`